# Item Disassembly into different items ERPnext

Tags: erpnext

Is there anyway to disassemble an item that contains two or multiple items.
And update the stock automatically with the disassembled items.
Thank you for your reply,
Regards
Rog

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think you should check the Manufacturing Module 
https://erpnext.org/docs/user/manual/en/manufacturing
The item you want to disassemble is considered as the row material item 
and the new items are the Finished item.
So basically you create production order for the Finished Item and use the raw material to automatically produce the required amount.